# get the value of an XML attribute using php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I am attempting to take a value from an attribute and use it in an array to insert it into a MySQL table.  My XML file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetMatchingProductForIdResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="9780596515898" IdType="ISBN" status="Success">
<Products xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
<Product>
  <Identifiers>
    <MarketplaceASIN>
      <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
      <ASIN>B0026OR39Y</ASIN>
    </MarketplaceASIN>
  </Identifiers>
```

and using php I need to extract out the value of Id in GetMatchingProductForIdResult.  So far my code is this:

```
    $parsed_xml = ProductId_xml($isbn);
    $isbn13 =(string)$parsed_xml->GetMatchingProductProductForIdResult[0]->attributes();
echo $isbn13['Id']; die;
```

I am getting no result from the echo statement, even if I change it to print_r or var_dump.  I have also tried:

```
    $amazonResult = array(
                            'isbn' => $parsed_xml->GetMatchingProductProductForIdResult[0]['Id'],
```

Which yielded no results either.  I am not sure where to go from here and any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify this a little bit, the value in Id will change for each record. So what is "9780596515898" this time could be Id="9780596312674" for the next record.  I need to know what each one is so I can insert them into the database with the other information I need.

Comment: Doesn't look like valid xml to me

Comment: I only posted the relevant section of the XML file.  I use it to extract other pieces of information and it works perfectly.

Comment: You could have a look at [PHP simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: @Bondye - thanks, but I need to get the value of Id, which this document doesn't really address.  I can access all of the other info just fine.

Comment: This document does address to all elements and attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can access the attributes if I close out the XML - otherwise all it does is throw errors.
You can access all attributes, or individually through simplexml:

```
$str = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetMatchingProductForIdResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="9780596515898" IdType="ISBN" status="Success">
<Products xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
<Product>
  <Identifiers>
    <MarketplaceASIN>
      <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
      <ASIN>B0026OR39Y</ASIN>
    </MarketplaceASIN>
  </Identifiers>
</Product>
</Products>
</GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
</GetMatchingProductForIdResponse>
XML;


$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

foreach($xml->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}

// Or access them directly:

echo $xml->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->attributes()->Id;
```

**Outputs:**

```
Id="9780596515898" IdType="ISBN" status="Success" 9780596515898
```

Comment: Thanks nickhar, accessing them directly is what I needed and it works great.

Comment: I scratched my head in the same way a long time ago! :)

Comment: Note that `GetMatchingProductForIdResult->attributes()->Id` can also be written as `GetMatchingProductForIdResult['Id']`